# Instantiated prefab loses components

Tags: unity-game-engine

I instantiated a prefab in a script. The GameObject that is created doesn't have any of the components from my prefab in the project view. My prefab is suppose to have a script component but when I instantiate it it has none.How can it happen?

```
IEnumerator StartDownload()
{
  WWW www = new WWW(Application.StreamingAssetsPath() + "/shadow.unity3d");

  yield return www;

  AssetBundle ab = www.assetBundle;
  AssetBundleRequest abr = ab.LoadAsync("shadow", typeof(GameObject));

  yield return abr;

  GameObject tmp = abr.asset as GameObject;
  LoadShaderAgain myScriptComponent = tmp.GetComponent<LoadShaderAgain>();

  if (myScriptComponent == null)
  {
      Debug.LogError("losing the script compoent");
  }

  GameObject obj = GameObject.Instantiate(tmp);
}
```

Comment: Please use the unity3d tag, instead of unity (which is not about the game engine).

Comment: Please also add the code you're using in your script.

Comment: No, i don't think it necessary. Just a regular loading workflow. `WWW www = new WWW(url); GameObject go = www.assetBundle.Load(assetName, assetType) as GameObject;`. Seems nothing to do with the script or the script component.

Comment: the code is actually really important, please post it. It seems you're not using a regular workflow, a regular one would be Resources.Load(path). It seems you are using asset bundles, this was impossible to asses just by looking at your question.

Comment: more to the point now, when building the asset bundle are you building them with references or are you just placing the "top level" game object in it?

Comment: OK, so: assetBundle.Load is NOT the same as instantiating a prefab. Please edit your question to include the code.

Comment: @hades2510 When building the asset bundle, of course the script component is added to the game object. The `BuildAssetBundleOptions` is `CollectDependencies | CompleteAssets`

Comment: @DanPuzey Juset before instantiating the prefab, i have tried `go.GetComponent<MyScript>()`, the result is `null`

Comment: Whatever is going on with the loading/instantiating why not add the component? [Docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html)

Comment: Sorry, the code is in my another computer which is off line, but i'm pretty sure there is no problem in the loading workflow, because not all the prefab will losing components.

Comment: @RoyHu: whatever you *think* is going wrong, people are repeatedly asking for the code to be shared. The reason for that is that nobody can help you if they can't see what you're doing. The behaviour you describe makes no sense, because loading a prefab obviously *can work* in Unity. The most likely culprit is in *your code*. Please share it! In the absence of code I can only vote to close this question as unanswerable.

Comment: It looks like the GameObject is null, so it's not that you loose the component.

Comment: @Catwood sorry, type error. `tmp` is not `null`, `myScriptComponent` is instead.

Comment: Did you actually ever apply the updates to your prefab? If you drag the prefab manually into a scene, are all the components there?

Comment: if you try to get the component after the GameObject is instantiated you still get a null component

Comment: one more thing, you should yield return abr and not yield return abr.asset, as per documentation if you access the asset before it is loaded the download will halt

Comment: @Bart Yes, all components there

Comment: @hades2510 no matter before or after instantiating, got null component.

Comment: can you check that the 2 metas for the LoadShaderAgain are the same? The meta from where you built the asset bundles and the meta on your current machine

Comment: @hades2510 Building and loading the asset bundle use the same script `LoadShaderAgain`.